# What is self.scale.endPoint chartJs v2.0?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying hard to add functionalities to my charts by re-writing draw chart functions of chartJS v1.x to v2.0. A lot of features inside the chart draw functions use "**self.scale.endPoint**"in v1.x but it looks like there are lots of changes in the v2.0 structure and I'm unable to find it. 
Like here :

```
// the min is required so animation does not start from below the axes
bar.y = Math.min(bar.y + radius, self.scale.endPoint - 1);
```

How can I use this value ?

JSFiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0dzp3jxw/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chartJS v2.x you must specify what axis you want to access (as they now support multiple). For your issue, you want to use the default y axis, which should be accessible in such a manner

```
this.chart.scales["y-axis-0"]
```

Although I haven't tested it myself, I think endPoint is now called bottom, and therefore you can get the same value like this:

```
this.chart.scales["y-axis-0"].bottom
```